# django session project cart

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display data that I put on a session for my shopping cart project that I'm developing,
but here I can't recover the product whose code I passed as a parameter

```
def index(request):
   mes_produits={'produits':[{'code':'2BG12','nom':'banane sucré','prix':1500}, 
   {'code':'MLO23','nom':'pomme de terre','prix':1800}]}
   parcou=mes_produits['produits']
   contex={'produits':parcou}
   return render(request,'shop/index.html',contex)


def cart_add(request, code):
   dico={'produits':[{'code':'2BG12','nom':'banane sucré','prix':1500}, 
   {'code':'MLO23','nom':'pomme de terre','prix':1800}]}
   mes_produits=dico['produits']
   selected_product = next((item for item in mes_produits if item["code"] == code), None)
   if selected_product != None:
     request.session['nom']=selected_product.get('nom')
     request.session['prix']=selected_product.get('prix')
   contex={'nom':request.session['nom'],'prix':request.session['prix']}
   return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html',contex)
```

car_detail.html

```
  {% for key,value in request.session.items %}
        Nom : {{value.nom}}  
        Prix : {{value.prix}}
  {% endfor %}
```

I get a blank page with the name of the keys only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session object is a dict, not a list of tuple. Try this code in template:

```
Nom : {{request.session.nom}}  
Prix : {{request.session.prix}}
```

But, you have already set the vars in context, so you can do:

```
Nom : {{nom}}  
Prix : {{prix}}

# And your views.py
def cart_add(request, code):
    dico={'produits':[{'code':'2BG12','nom':'banane sucré','prix':1500}, 
    {'code':'MLO23','nom':'pomme de terre','prix':1800}]}
    mes_produits=dico['produits']
    selected_product = next((item for item in mes_produits if item["code"] == code), None)
    if selected_product != None:
        context={
           'nom':selected_product.get('nom'),
           'prix':selected_product.get('prix')
        }
     else:
         context = {}
     return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html',context)
```

Maybe you do not understand session usage?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: How to do here to add two different products
because if I try to add another product, I have the same product which was put in session first

Comment: you can make a list in context: context = {'products': [{'nom': p1.get('nom'), 'prix': p1.get('prix')}, {'nom': p2.get('nom'), 'prix': p2.get('prix')}]}. 
But i think it is better, you read the Django doc for getting base of django framework usage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/http/views/